# How to remove html tag in php?

Tags: php, html

I want to remove this code when my cmd value=compare,how i do this?

Here is my code:

```
<h1 style="margin-top:24px;"><?=ucfirst($_GET['page5'])?><? if($_POST['mode']=='test' || $_GET['mode']=='test') { print " (Test Mode)"; } ?></h1>

if($_GET['cmd']=='compare' && !$_POST)
{
}
```

I used this code:

```
$dom = str_get_html($html);

// ...or construct dom from file/url
$dom = file_get_html($path);

// strip h1 tags (and their content)
 foreach ($dom->find('h1') as $node) {
$node->outertext = '';
}
```

How i remove above code when cmd=compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If I have well understood your question.)
I cannot check the exact syntax and php is not my main language, but that's something I already done: I would write like this

```
if($_GET['cmd']=='compare' && !$_POST)
{
    [here comes the optional HTML code, may inclu php parts et]
}
```

So if the condition is not met, the code simply won't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve this by having a cookie for your "Test Mode".
Use `setCookie("name","value",time() + 60);`
That will create a 1 minute long cookie for your test mode.

Then add an additional condition:
`if($_COOKIE['name']) {
// CONTENT 
}`